# App that can change your voice into different characters voices

Tags: audio, voice-recording

Say you want to sound like Mark Hamill (aka The Joker from the *Arkham* games), or Roger (the alien from *American Dad*). Is there an app that can do that?

I am open to any price and platform: web app or Windows/Mac/Linux/Android/iOS app.

It must have voices for at least a few persons/characters.

Comment: Does it need to be able to read printed text in a given voice (text to speech), or adjust your spoken voice's sound to sound like another voice? If the latter, do you need it to modify sound as you speak it, or can it take a recording and convert it after the fact?

Answer (score 0):

[MorphVOX](http://screamingbee.com/Product/MorphVOX.aspx) has some nice voices/distortions and options to tune them. You can use this software for instance with Skype. But it doesn't have the specific characters you ask for.